# using the resource in a view to bootstrap app's data

Tags: django, tastypie

I'd like to use my resource in a view to bootstrap app's data.
I saw a way of doing it in the cookbook: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views

However, I was wondering whether there is a more straightforward way to do it?
Moreover, unlike the example, I want to return several objects so I used obj_get_list()[0:20] but the bundle is looking for a "pk" so I cannot use it like that. It does not work. How would you do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `get_object_list()` or just `_meta.queryset()` ? But if you're not performing a GET request from within your view (which would really be using you API) then I wonder if it's not better to just do `Model.objects.all()`.